# Setting a property doesn't work - dumb syntax error?

Tags: python, properties

I'm probably making some elementary mistake...

When I initialize and look at a property of an object, fine. But if I try to set it, the object doesn't update itself.  I'm trying to define a property which I can set and get.   To make it interesting, this rectangle stores twice its width instead of the width, so the getter and setter have something to do besides just copying.

```
class Rect:
    """simple rectangle (size only) which remembers double its w,h
       as demo of properties
    """

    def __init__(self, name, w):
        self.name=name
        self.dwidth=2*w

    def dump(self):
    print "dwidth = %f"  %  (self.dwidth,)


    def _width(self):
        return self.dwidth/2.0

    def _setwidth(self,w):
        print "setting w=", w
        self.dwidth=2*w
        print "now have .dwidth=", self.dwidth

    width =property(fget=_width, fset=_setwidth)
```

The .dwidth member variable would normally be private, but I want to peek at it easily in an interactive session.  In a Python command line, I try it out:

```
bash 0=> python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from rectzzz import *
>>> a = Rect("ack", 10.0)
>>> a.dump()
dwidth = 20.000000
>>> a.width
10.0
>>> a.width=100
>>> a.width
100
>>> a.dump()
dwidth = 20.000000
>>> a.dwidth
20.0
>>>
```

Why does .width seem to update, but the object's actual state as told by dump() and .dwidth not change?  I'm especially puzzled why I never see "setting w=" followed by a number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Rect:
    """simple rectangle (size only) which remembers double its w,h
       as demo of properties
    """
```

Should be:

```
class Rect(object):
    """simple rectangle (size only) which remembers double its w,h
       as demo of properties
    """
```

In python 2.x, `property` only works properly if you inherit from `object`, so that you get the new style class. By default you get old-style classes for backwards compatibility. This has been fixed in python 3.x.

Comment: That's it!  I suffer for my lack of paying attention to the talk about new vs old objects. Somehow I got the idea the (object) was optional. Only in 3.x, but I am using 2.7 today.